# Laravel 4.2 - Finding Facebook Mutual Friends with artdarek/oauth-4-laravel

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-4, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get the mutual friends between the user logging in and some other person. I am using Laravel 4.2 and [artdarek/oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel). I can get this sample script to work just fine:

```
public function loginWithFacebook() {

    // get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );

    // get fb service
    $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

        // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode( $fb->request( '/me' ), true );

        $message = 'Your unique facebook user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
        echo $message. "<br/>";

        //Var_dump
        //display whole array().
        dd($result);

    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else {
        // get fb authorization
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();

        // return to facebook login url
         return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }

}
```

But I don't know the syntax to request mutual friends for another facebook id, say 1457655547838343. I know the key is probably with line 18, specifically `$fb->request( '/me' )`. I've tried about 100 different things, including `$fb->request( '/me/mutualfriends/1457655547838343' )` and others. Can somebody please just point me in the right direction?

Comment: mutualfriends was only available in API v1.0, it has been removed from API 2.0 on.

Comment: I should have clarified that I don't actually need the list of mutual friends, I just need the COUNT of mutual friends. I know this can be achieved because I was able to get a working javascript version of it. The problem with the javascript version, however, is that it requires a popup window (which then closes itself once the script has executed). I don't want the popup window. Any other advice?

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say here … if you are able to make an API call in JavaScript, then you should be able to make the same API call server-side …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, Facebook has changed their policies to only allow an application to see mutual friends WHO HAVE ALSO SIGNED IN THROUGH THE APP. This limitation makes the mutual friend thing pretty useless for what I was trying to do.

Also, I ended up just using [Facebook's official php SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0) and everything else I was trying to do works great.